# Issues when formatting a picture within a footnote

Tags: graphics, formatting, footnotes

Hi all I am attempting to create something along the lines of:

[image: Picture 1]

But so far the closest that I can get is:

[image: Picture 2]

My code is:

```
\footnote{\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.1\textwidth}
\vspace{-15pt}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{Figure.png}
\vspace{-20pt}
\end{wrapfigure} Figure 13... Figure 13... Figure 13... Figure 13... Figure 13... Figure 13... Figure 13... Figure 13... Figure 13... \vspace{0.55cm}}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I have tried using `\parbox` but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: When posting the code, you should try to provide a full compilable minimal working example (MWE). That means, in particular, adding `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{...}\begin{document}...\end{document}`, where you should only add those packages that are strictly necessary to compile.

Comment: While it might be possible, the question is a) whether images should appear in footnotes and b) if a `wrapfigure` should appear there ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Most things are possible, with a little maneuvering:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Text\footnote{%
  \raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
  \quad%\hspace{1em}
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr0.9\linewidth-1em-1.8em}{\strut
  Footnote text with some more text that should span multiple lines.%
  \strut}}
and another footnote\footnote{Some footnote.}.
Here is another footnote\footnote{%
  \leavevmode
  \rlap{\smash{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}{\includegraphics[width=0.1\linewidth]{example-image-b}}}}%
  \hspace*{-1.8em}\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{%
    \parshape 3 \dimexpr0.1\linewidth+1em+1.8em\relax \dimexpr0.9\linewidth-1em-1.8em\relax
      \dimexpr0.1\linewidth+1em+1.8em\relax \dimexpr0.9\linewidth-1em-1.8em\relax
      0pt \linewidth
    Footnote text with some more text that should span multiple lines and perhaps some more, depending on the context.%
  }}

\end{document}
```

I've used the standard [`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) class, which sets its footnote markers in a box of width `1.8em` (hence the use of `1.8em` everywhere in the calculations).

The difficulty of the code correlates with whether you want the footnote text to wrap the image or not. If you don't want it wrapped (footnote 1 above), then you can simply place the text in a `[t]`op-aligned `\parbox` of specified width: `0.9\linewidth` (to accommodate for the `0.1\linewidth` image width) *minus* `1em` (or `\quad` - the gap between the image and the text, if you use one) *minus* `1.8em` (the footnote marker width, as mentioned before).

If you want it to wrap, you'd follow a similar procedure, but this time you're actually setting a `\parbox` over top of the footnote marker and image. So, you `\smash` the image and set it with zero width (`\rlap` - a zero-width box with over`lap`ping to the `r`ight). Once the image is set, we undo the space from the footnote marker (`\hspace*{-1.8em}`) and set the footnote in a full-width - `\linewidth` - `\parbox`. The `\parshape` usage is similar to what [`wrapfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig) allows you to do in wrapping paragraph text. It has the format

```
\parshape <n> <i1> <w1> <i2> <w2> ... <in> <wn>
```

where you want to shape `n` lines, the first of which has `i`ndent `<i1>` and `w`idth `<w1>`, the second of which has `i`ndent `<i2>` and `w`idth `<w2>`... etc. Lines `n+1` and onward will duplicate the specification for line `n` - an `i`ndent of `<in>` and `w`idth of `<wn>`.

Using `\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox}` ensures that the top of the image is roughly aligned with the top of the ascenders in the text.

This solution is most certainly very specific to the default `article` class.

Comment: i was attempting something with a `minipage` and `\hangindent` or `\parshape`, but this looks reasonable, so i won't continue.  however, you might be able to make use of `\ht\strutbox` instead of `.7\baselineskip` for the desired height of the box.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Great suggestion!